# Clojure からJavaの関数呼び出し

Tags: clojure

例として

```
void sample(int[] a){
  a[0] = 0;
}
```

のような関数は入力として引数に配列を渡し,結果は渡された配列に格納して結果を返す場合どのようにプログラムを書けばいいのでしょうか.

Comment: あんまり必要性がないような気がします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

例えば Java のコードが以下の様なプリミティブな int 配列の場合は

```
public class ClojureSample {
    public static void sample(int[] a){
        a[0] = 0;
    }
}
```

Clojure 側でも list でなく int-array を使わないといけません。

```
(let [a (int-array 3 [1 2 3])]
  (println (nth a 0))
  (. ClojureSample (sample a))
  (println (nth a 0)))
```

結果

```
1
0
```